# gpg use sha1 even with --digest-algo SHA512?

Tags: gnupg

After I used this code to encrypt gpg.txt

```
$ gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 --digest-algo SHA512 "GPG.txt"
```

I checked the result to see if it was encrypted with AES256 and hashed with SHA512

```
$ gpg --list-packets GPG.txt.gpg
symkey enc packet: version 4, cipher 9, s2k 3, ***hash 2***
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
```

I found Cipher=9, which is AES256 as I asked, but Hash=2, which stands for SHA1 and is not 10=SHA512 as I had wanted!

Why did this happen?  Does anyone know how to force gpg to use SHA512 instead of SHA1?

Comment: It seems like you are looking at the *key* packet. That's the part of the encrypted file that holds the actual encryption key. From the looks of it, the data itself isn't hashed at all (which makes sense, you are asking for symmetric encryption). Have you tried using asymmetric encryption instead and seeing if that makes any difference?

Comment: From the looks of it, the data itself isn't hashed at all (which makes sense, you are asking for symmetric encryption), what u mean?

Comment: Doesn't the hash make a difference only for signatures?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hate to say it, but **read the gpg man page.**

The `--digest-algo` option chooses a message digest algorithm ... for the message ... i.e., if you create a signature.

The `--s2k-digest-algo` option sets what algo is used to hash the passphrases. If you set *THAT* to sha512, then you'll see `hash 10` on that symkey enc packet line.

In response to your questions in the below comment:

- Use `--cipher-algo` to specify the symmetric cipher algorithm used to actually encrypt the message.
- Use `--digest-algo` to specify the digest algorithm used to hash the message when signing.
- Use `--s2k-digest-algo` to specify the digest algorithm used for hashing passphrases in various operations (e.g., the symmetric passphrase specified when using `-c`).